# php fopen with parameter

Tags: php, fopen

I have this simple script, where I need to call other file on server with specified $value. The other file has to take the $value and process it, however It seems the value is not transfered for some reason.

```
foreach ($ids as $value)  {     
    @fopen("http://www.blabla.com/script.php?term=$value", "r");}
```

the other file processes it like this

```
if ($_GET["term"]!="") {  
  $term=htmlspecialchars($_GET["term"]);
  $title=$term;
  ...
```

if I call the 2nd file directly it works just fine but if I call it through fopen it's not passing the variable... thanks

Comment: yes it opens the file but doesn't pass the variable - the 2nd script is processed but with empty $term variable for some reason...

Comment: it is definitely non empty. i tried even hardcoding it in the fopen part like `@fopen("http://www.blabla.com/script.php?term=EXAMPLETERM", "r");` and it doesn't pass it...

Comment: Noticed that you're using `@`; could you remove that, set `error_reporting(~0);` and see if there are any warnings?

Comment: no change and no errors reported :/

Comment: Could you add the output of `print_r(stream_get_meta_data($f))` whereby `$f` is the return value of `fopen()`?

Comment: Does both documents (script.php and main) have same encoding? Is this blabla.com is your website (do you have control over it's server)?

Comment: yes Ultra both scripts are in the same folder on my own dedicated server

Comment: If both scripts are in the same folder, you don't have to resort to making HTTP requests.

Comment: the output: (
    [wrapper_data] => Array
        (
            [0] => HTTP/1.1 200 OK
            [1] => Server: nginx/1.0.15
            [2] => Date: Tue, 30 Sep 2014 08:23:47 GMT
            [3] => Content-Type: text/html
            [4] => Connection: close
            [5] => X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.17
        )

    [wrapper_type] => http
    [stream_type] => tcp_socket/ssl
    [mode] => r
    [unread_bytes] => 240
    [seekable] => 
    [uri] => http://www.blabla.com/script.php?term=myterm
    [timed_out] => 
    [blocked] => 1
    [eof] => 
)

Comment: [timed_out] => [blocked] seems bit suspicious...

Comment: what would you suggest instead of HTTP requests Ja͢ck?

Comment: The meta data looks fine to me; perhaps you could try `file_get_contents()` instead of `fopen()` though; and if both scripts are in the same folder, move all functions of script #2 into a third script and use those functions in both your scripts.

Comment: "it's not passing the variable" - I'm sure that's not true. From the comments it looks the script doesn't get executed at all.

Comment: it does get exectuted - the 2nd script is supposed to create .html file with content generated through the passed $value. it generates the file but $value is empty...

Comment: i added source code of the 2nd script, pls check it...

Comment: OMG i got it... it's not passing the value ONLY IF it contains special national characters - so it's problem with encoding. if i use only english letters it works just fine...

Comment: You said it didn't work with `http://www.blabla.com/script.php?term=EXAMPLETERM` ... so what gives? Obviously, you're supposed to use `http_build_query()` to properly escape the values.

Comment: i used the special character in EXAMPLETERM too in this direct query, that's why... anyway thx for help!